# post hoc power analysis for SEM model?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, statistical-power, post-hoc

What are my options for conducting any sort of power analysis post hoc? And if not a post hoc power analysis, what should I report?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do post hoc power analysis. See [Hoenig & Heisey (2001, *The American Statistician*)](https://doi.org/10.1198/000313001300339897).

Comment: If not a post hoc analysis, what should I report?

Comment: Report the results of your analysis, along with any effect sizes that make sense in your context.